# Required fields show the placeholder while non required fields do not

Tags: html, css

I have some required fields in my html code, but they do not show the place holder until I specify that the field is required. I do not know why...

```html
<input class="text" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter new password" required="">
<br>
<input class="text" type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Enter new phone number">
```

The second input does not show the place holder when I run the code.

Comment: I can see placeholder on both inputs

Comment: I mean on the browser.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce this. Please post a [mre], preferably as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: I have added your code into a snippet, you can see there is  placeholder, please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: when I run the code the placeholder on second input field does not show

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. When you click "Run code snippet" do you see the placeholder? Which browser are you using?

Comment: may be dumb but try to restart your pc

Comment: Can you also give us the screenshot of the error shows in your browser? And what type of browser are you using? Have you tried it on other browsers?